# unexpected result when mapping two arrays with undefined values

Tags: javascript, dictionary, undefined

Why does this map return different results when I apply it on two arrays that are supposed to be perfectly equal to each other?

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];
a.length = 7;
let b = [1, 2, 3, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined];
console.log("a: " + a); //a: 1,2,3,,,,
console.log("b: " + b); //b: 1,2,3,,,,
console.log("It is " + a.every((x, i) => x === b[i]) + " that these arrays are perfectly equal."); //It is true that these arrays are perfectly equal.
a = a.map(x => 1);
b = b.map(x => 1);
console.log("a: " + a); //a: 1,1,1,,,,
console.log("b: " + b); //b: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) works only for non sparsed items and `toString` takes [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), which returns an empty string for sparse, `undefined`, `null` values or empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Array a has 4-7 just as empty. In b 4-7 are undefined. After using the map function, that difference is showing up as "1,1,1,,,," and "1,1,1,1,1,1,1"

Answer (score 0):

These two arrays are not the same.
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DRNz.png)

Due to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) when you change the length of an array javascript injects "empty statement" in new indexes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).